# Restore same database multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have my local database called `CBS` and on the production server there is the same database. Sometimes I want to make a backup on production and want to restore it on my local machine. With SQL Server 2008 I had no problems but now I can't do that.

To restore the production database I changed the destination database from `CBS` to `CBS_PROD`. I also changed the file names of the destination database. After restore the `CBS_PROD` is OK but my former local `CBS` database is in state "Restoring...".

Please help.

Thanks
Andi

Comment: Could you "Refresh" the database tree? Right Click on `Databases` then hit on the `Refresh` button.

Comment: Yes, still restoring....

Comment: Did you restore with  "WITH RECOVERY" option ??

Comment: Yes, see http://d.pr/i/HfFa. Funny is, I tried it a second time. Same DB Backup, changed destination to CBS_PROD2 and that worked. Database CBS still in restoring state but CBS_PROD is OK. I also checket it on another server, same problem.

Comment: OK, just called `RESTORE DATABASE CBS` now and the CBS database is back again. Now I have `CBS`, `CBS_PROD` and `CBS_PROD2` and everything is OK. But I don't unterstand it.

Comment: Now third try after `CBS` is back. Im getting the message "A teil-log Backup of the source database will be taken..." http://d.pr/i/fYCe. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Andi if you want to restore a database to a point in time then we make use of Restoring a database WITH NORECOVERY so we can restore any differential backups transactional log back ups or tail-log backups to get to that point in time where database was in the "right" state. whatever may be the case the very last restore you do , you will have to do it with "WITH RECOVERY" option to bring database online in a useable state. and pleas if the answer was helpful accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Executing this statement

```
RESTORE DATABASE DataBase_Name 
WITH RECOVERY
GO
```

If you are using SSMS to restore the database make sure you select the following option in "Recovery State" Section.
[image]